# Performance of CSS3 accordion vs Javascript (Hardware accelaretad) accordion

Tags: javascript, css

Which version of accordion is most smooth, fastest and without lags?

Is better `pure CSS3` or something like this `javascript accelerated` ?

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metalhaze/3DWZu/)</kbd>

Which have best performance?

Thanks for any opinions!

Comment: A good question, but sadly not one we can answer for you on StackOverflow.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Thanks. Yes I searching most native feel to my webapp...

Comment: [An article you should read.](http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transitions are always faster, as they do not need to run a cycle to process the JavaScript.

Most specifically, CSS transitions changing **scale, opacity and rotation** are fastest because they do not trigger a page-wide redraw.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is both. Default to CSS3 and use Modernizr to help you decide when to fall back to Javascript.

http://modernizr.com